# Linear thermal expansion of a rod at different end temperatures with variable thermal expansion

Tags: thermal-conductivity, cryogenics

I am trying to wrap my head around a thought experiment.

If I have a thin rod of a uniform material (304SS for example) and hold one end at a relatively high temperature (say 250K) and the other end at a relatively low temperature (say 10K), I start to be outside the realm of where the coefficient of linear expansion can be assumed to be a single number. Looking at the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) I think the steady state condition of the rod is going to be a linear thermal gradient, but looking at [properties of 304SS](https://trc.nist.gov/cryogenics/materials/304Stainless/304Stainless_rev.htm) the linear expansion is definitely temperature dependent across the ranges I am considering.

All examples I can find of secant vs tangent CTE evaluations are for a uniform heating condition, and because the equations for the secant data are dependent on a fixed reference temperature I am struggling to understand how the temperature dependent thermal expansion propagates through the sample. In my mind, if I know the rod has a fixed length at some temperature (say at 250K I know it's .5 meters), the length change of the section of the rod that is at 240K would be different than the length change of the section of the rod that is at 100K. I think the secant data accounts for this in a system where the entire sample is affected (which is why you can go point to point) but with a temperature gradient I am thinking this is going to be an integral of some sort, covering the change between individual temperature points and the corresponding cumulative length change. The only problem with this theory is when I attempt to calculate this I end up with the exact same expansion as the Secant point to point calculation, which I can't reason to be true.

Answer (score 0):

> I am struggling to understand how the temperature dependent thermal expansion propagates through the sample.

This is addressed through integration. For example, the total change in length relative to the length at reference temperature $T_0$ is

$$\Delta L=\int_0^L\alpha(T)[T(x)-T_0]\,dx,$$

with temperature-dependent thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha(T)$, local temperature $T(x)$, and distance $x$ along the length $L$.

The interpretation is that you're adding up the expansion over many infinitesimal regions, each with their own approximately constant temperature and corresponding single thermal expansion coefficient.

You can try to estimate or fit analytical functions to $\alpha(T)$ and $T(x)$ and then try to perform the integration analytically, or you can perform numerical integration with functions or a look-up table and interpolation.